# send xmpp <message> to component on other domain

Tags: xmpp, openfire, dyndns

step 1:on the same domain(.myserver.kicks-ass.net),  i able to send  to the mycomponent,succesfully.

step 2:when i login to other domain ,example gmail.com and try send   to another user on test@.myserver.kicks-ass.net, success as well.

step 3:just like step2, but i send the  to  mycomponent.myserver.kicks-ass.net , i get below error

```
<message xmlns='jabber:client'
         to='mycomponent.myserver.kicks-ass.net'
         from='user@gmail.com/123'
         type='chat'>
<body>
just t4st
</body>
<x xmlns='jabber:x:event'>
<offline/>
<composing/>
</x>
</message>
<message xmlns='jabber:client'
         to='user@gmail.com/123'
         from='mycomponent.myserver.kicks-ass.net'
         type='error'>
<body>
just t4st
</body>
<x xmlns='jabber:x:event'>
<offline/>
<composing/>
</x>
<error code='404'
       type='cancel'>
<remote-server-not-found xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
</error>
</message>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an SRV record for:

```
_xmpp-server._tcp.mycomponent.myserver.kicks-ass.net
```

You can test for this with the following shell command:

```
 % dig +short -t SRV _xmpp-server._tcp.mycomponent.myserver.kicks-ass.net.
```

Can you telnet to that host/port from outside your network?  For example:

```
% dig +short -t SRV _xmpp-server._tcp.jabber.org.
30 30 5269 hermes.jabber.org.
% telnet hermes.jabber.org 5269
Trying 208.68.163.220...
Connected to hermes.jabber.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
<<
<stream:error><bad-format xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/></stream:error></stream:stream>
Connection closed by foreign host
```

Comment: i'm using dyndns,  how to i add  _xmpp-server._tcp.mycomponent.myserver.kicks-ass.net    ?

Comment: Is myserver.kicks-ass.net managed directly by dyndns, or are you just using them to map an A record on to that name?  If the former, you'll need to use the expert interface (see: http://www.dyndns.com/support/kb/record_types_supported_in_custom_dns_expert_interface.html).  If the latter, just put that A record name as the target of the SRV.

Comment: @JoeHildebrand I stuck with configuring DynDNS for my local. May you look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304810/domain-name-for-my-pc-configure-router-how-to please? Thanks!